# How to create view from External http request json and Internal Database using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to combine external json using request and Internal Database, But the condition is when someone call API we need to get **empidlong** from Model for call external API from specific URL, Then external API will return JSON and i need to merge this JSON with my json that create by Django REST API Framework

Here is my code

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models
import requests
from django.core.files import File
from urllib import request
import os


# Create your models here.
class getData(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    period = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    plate_no = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
    project_code = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    costcenter = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    empidlong = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'car_information'
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import getData


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = getData
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .models import getData
from .serializers import CarSerializer

import requests


class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = getData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    #search_fields = ('plate_no')
    __basic_fields = ('plate_no',)
    search_fields = __basic_fields

    serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = serializer.data
    for a in data: 
        empid= a['empidlong']
        r = requests.get('http://192.168.10.32/Employees/'+empid)


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = getData.objects.all()
        emp = self.request.query_params.get('emp', None)
        if emp is not None:
            queryset =  queryset.filter(empidlong=emp)

        return queryset
```

I have no idea how to do it. I stuck this for week.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you expecting the json from? if from a user, you can access the json from the request. Then you can use it in your orm query. You CarViewSet seem to be doing way more than it should be. What is your goal exactly?

Comment: I need to display merged API from getData Model and JSON from http://192.168.10.32

Comment: `192.168.10.32` ip has nothing.